# Identify the factors with the highest counts and sums within each combination of two grouping variables

Tags: r, class, classification

For this study, we recorded the species and diameter at breast height (dbh) for every tree > 1.5m in height and >1.8 cm in diameter within a 100m<sup>2</sup> circular plot. There were 100+ circular plots sampled.

I would like to identify the most representative tree species in each of four diameter classes. The diameter classes are sapling (2.5-8 cm), pole (>8-18 cm), mature (>18-28 cm) and large (>28 cm).

If possible I would like an example of how to select the most representative species in each class by density (count of each species in each class) and also by volume (basal area).

I have posted a question on crossvalidated.com regarding which method (density or volume) is more appropriate...

https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/148734/57117

Note, the name of each site sampled (`location`) does not follow any kind of pattern. The names were assigned based on the location in the dataset they were sub-sampled from. Also, if there are no species within a certain diameter class for a site, `NA` will work.

Here is an example dataset with 15 locations sampled and 1,200 trees measured. My data are very similar to the following example data.

```
tree.species<-c("PSME", "PIEN", "LAOC", "POTR", "SALIX")
tree.diameters<- data.frame(location= paste0(sample(LETTERS[c(2,4,6,8)], 4, replace=TRUE),sample(seq(006,250,57), 1200, replace = TRUE)), 
                            dbh= c(rep(3.81,200),rnorm(350, mean = 6.32, sd=1.5),rnorm(50, mean = 75, sd=6),
                                   runif(550, min=20, max=100),rnorm(50, mean = 150, sd=2.3)), #Units in cm
                            species = factor(sample(tree.species, 1200, replace=TRUE)))

#Add basal area (m sq. per ha)
tree.diameters$basal.area=100*(pi*((tree.diameters$dbh/2)^2)/(4*10000)) 

#Order the data
tree.diameters<-tree.diameters[order(tree.diameters$location, tree.diameters$dbh,tree.diameters$species),]

> head(tree.diameters, n=15)
    location      dbh species basal.area
426     B120 3.303363    PSME 0.02142607
358     B120 3.657538   SALIX 0.02626682
450     B120 3.667190    PSME 0.02640565
150     B120 3.810000    PIEN 0.02850230
94      B120 3.810000    POTR 0.02850230
10      B120 3.810000    PSME 0.02850230
90      B120 3.810000    PSME 0.02850230
18      B120 3.810000   SALIX 0.02850230
134     B120 3.810000   SALIX 0.02850230
194     B120 3.810000   SALIX 0.02850230
274     B120 3.979974   SALIX 0.03110214
290     B120 5.345510   SALIX 0.05610586
310     B120 5.480217    POTR 0.05896921
254     B120 5.625061   SALIX 0.06212757
478     B120 5.852126    LAOC 0.06724456
```

The general method I have been working on for selecting by *density* looks something like code below for `location=="B120"` & `location=="B177"` , but I am not sure how to iterate it and place all the results into a list or data.frame. I am also unsure how to calculate the same thing for *volume* (`basal.area`)

```
> names(which(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                          location == "B120" & dbh < 8, 
+                          select=species))
+             ==max(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                                location == "B120" & dbh < 8,
+                                select=species)))))
[1] "SALIX"
> 
> names(which(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                          location == "B120" & dbh >= 8 | dbh < 18, 
+                          select=species))
+             ==max(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                                location == "B120" & dbh >= 8 | dbh < 18,
+                                select=species)))))
[1] "POTR"
> 
> names(which(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                          location == "B120" & dbh >= 18 | dbh < 28, 
+                          select=species))
+             ==max(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                                location == "B120" & dbh >= 18 | dbh < 28,
+                                select=species)))))
[1] "POTR"
> names(which(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                          location == "B120" & dbh > 28, 
+                          select=species))
+             ==max(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                                location == "B120" & dbh > 28, 
+                                select=species)))))
[1] "PIEN"
> #Location "B120"
> names(which(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                          location == "B120" & dbh < 8, 
+                          select=species))
+             ==max(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                                location == "B120" & dbh < 8,
+                                select=species)))))
[1] "SALIX"
> 
> names(which(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                          location == "B120" & dbh >= 8 | dbh < 18, 
+                          select=species))
+             ==max(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                                location == "B120" & dbh >= 8 | dbh < 18,
+                                select=species)))))
[1] "POTR"
> 
> names(which(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                          location == "B120" & dbh >= 18 | dbh < 28, 
+                          select=species))
+             ==max(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                                location == "B120" & dbh >= 18 | dbh < 28,
+                                select=species)))))
[1] "POTR"
> 
> names(which(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                          location == "B120" & dbh > 28, 
+                          select=species))
+             ==max(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                                location == "B120" & dbh > 28, 
+                                select=species)))))
[1] "PIEN"
> 
> #Location "B177"
> names(which(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                          location == "B177" & dbh < 8, 
+                          select=species))
+             ==max(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                                location == "B177" & dbh < 8,
+                                select=species)))))
[1] "POTR"
> 
> names(which(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                          location == "B177" & dbh >= 8 | dbh < 18, 
+                          select=species))
+             ==max(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                                location == "B177" & dbh >= 8 | dbh < 18,
+                                select=species)))))
[1] "POTR"
> 
> names(which(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                          location == "B177" & dbh >= 18 | dbh < 28, 
+                          select=species))
+             ==max(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                                location == "B177" & dbh >= 18 | dbh < 28,
+                                select=species)))))
[1] "POTR"
> 
> names(which(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                          location == "B177" & dbh > 28, 
+                          select=species))
+             ==max(table(subset(tree.diameters, 
+                                location == "B177" & dbh > 28, 
+                                select=species)))))
[1] "PSME"
```

I would like the output to resemble something like this (except with `vol.i` filled in for each class).

```
location den.sap den.pole den.mat den.lrg vol.sap vol.pole vol.mat vol.lrg
B120     SALIX   POTR     POTR    PIEN    ?       ?        ?       ?
B177     POTR    POTR     POTR    PSME    ?       ?        ?       ?
```

Comment: Also, I wasn't sure on the most appropriate tags or title for this question. I am welcome to any suggestions and I will change accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: A more useful title could be something like "Identify the factors with the highest counts and sums within each combination of two grouping variables" - the factors being the tree species and the grouping variables being location & size classification.

Comment: @SamFirke Thanks again for your input. The title of the question has been changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question asks a lot - but it's well-documented, and it provides a nice chance to showcase the [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) and [tidyr](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/07/22/introducing-tidyr/) packages.  So here goes.

First categorize the trees by size:

```
library(dplyr) ; library(tidyr)
tree.diameters <- tree.diameters %>%
  mutate(size = ifelse(dbh <= 8, "sapling",
                        ifelse(dbh <= 18, "pole",
                              ifelse(dbh <= 28, "mature", "large"))))
```

Calculate the counts and total volume for each location/species/size combination:

```
treesummary <- tree.diameters %>%
  group_by(location, species, size) %>%
  summarise(vol = sum(basal.area), count = n())
```

Lastly, select the maximum species for each location/size combination and spread that long table into a wide format.  Repeat for volume and join the two results tables together.

```
result <- inner_join(
  treesummary %>%
    group_by(location, size) %>%
    arrange(-count) %>%
    slice(1) %>%
    select(-count, -vol) %>%
    spread(size, species) %>%
    setNames(c("location", paste0("den.", names(.)[-1]))),

  treesummary %>%
    group_by(location, size) %>%
    arrange(-vol) %>%
    slice(1) %>%
    select(-count, -vol) %>%
    spread(size, species) %>%
    setNames(c("location", paste0("vol.", names(.)[-1]))),

  by = "location"
)
```

Yields:

```
result

   location den.large den.mature den.pole den.sapling vol.large vol.mature vol.pole vol.sapling
1      B120      LAOC       LAOC     PIEN        LAOC      LAOC       LAOC     PSME        POTR
2      B177      PSME       PIEN     LAOC        POTR      PSME       PIEN     LAOC        POTR
3      B234      POTR       PIEN     LAOC        POTR      PSME       PIEN     LAOC        POTR
4        B6     SALIX       PIEN     PSME        POTR      PSME       PIEN     PSME        POTR
5       B63     SALIX       PIEN     PIEN        PIEN     SALIX       PIEN     PIEN        PIEN
6      F120      PSME       POTR     POTR        PIEN      PSME       PSME     POTR        PIEN
7      F177      PIEN       POTR    SALIX       SALIX      PIEN       POTR    SALIX       SALIX
8      F234      PIEN       PIEN     LAOC       SALIX      PIEN       PIEN     LAOC       SALIX
9        F6      LAOC      SALIX     PIEN        PSME      PSME      SALIX     PIEN        PSME
10      F63      PIEN      SALIX     POTR        PIEN      PIEN      SALIX     POTR        PIEN
```

Comment: This works perfectly and is a very simple and well written answer. I appreciate the time an effort you put into answering my question. I am going to have a lot of fun going through the code to see how the functions in `dplyr` and `tidyr` accomplish the task. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad I could help.  The vignettes for each package that I linked to should be a help in learning how these functions work.